how to use dnsmasq for compressing large hosts file in windows?
actually  dns client is causing issues with my 11.8 MB hosts file which has 63k lines to be exact  and I have already used hosts file compressors which removes duplicates and puts 9 websites (i use for blocking) in a single line to reduce size .but still I am facing connectivity issues.
on the below link in comments they say to use dnsmasq but I dont know what to do.
https://www.reddit.com/r/privacy/comments/cbs5zv/query_disadvantages_of_a_large_hosts_file/
enter image description here

you could use dnsmasq as a local DNS server by running it in WSL or other linux VM (for example: https://ipv6.rs/tutorial/Windows_10/dnsmasq/), but it can get quite complex to configure. Where are you getting that many entries from? There are many ways to ignore the hosts file entirely, so there are usually better "blocking" options depending on what you're trying to accomplish
